# Yii2 how to use frontend assets in modules of yii2 advanced app

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I have asset created in frontend/assets/AppAssetTest in yii2 advanced app.
I have to use this asset in views of modules.
I am registering this asset in views of modules using following code but my asset is not getting registered:

```
    use frontend\assets\AppAssetTest;
    AppAssetTest::register($this);
```

Can any one help in achieving this?

Comment: Have u defined namespace in AppAssetsTest.php     `namespace frontend\assets;`  ?

Comment: yes i have namespace defined

Comment: can u post u'r AppAssetTest file and layout files code?  There is also a demo [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7o_wN8eHr4)